# Starting application by using SSH Module from python

Tags: python, c++, ssh, remote-access

How could I start an application with the ssh module from python on a remote system? I've tried

```
from shh import SSHClient

client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect("192.168.12.130", username="user", password="password")
stdout = client.exec_command('/path/to/application/app')
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
```

but it seems not to work.. In other words, I want to start an c++-application on a remote system and get access to the std::out stream. Other solutions are welcome

Comment: what kind of "not work" do you get?

Comment: I get only "Process exited with return code 0". The app was in a virtualbox so I'can see that the app didn't start and I also get no output from the print function.